# snort multiple excluded SHELLCODE_PORTS

Tags: snort

I read somewhere that it wasn't possible to specify multiple ports to 
exclude for shellcode is that correct? if not is the following 
correct?

## List of ports you want to look for SHELLCODE on.

portvar SHELLCODE_PORTS ![21,25,80,143,587,8889]

I'm using snort 2905

Comment: Should be on Serverfault

Answer (score 0):

Try it.  If Snort doesn't like the syntax, it should throwback a fatal parsing error.  I believe, though, that syntax is better implemented as:

```
portvar SHELLCODE_PORTS [21,25,80,143,587,8889]
```

I.e., without the negation, and then used in a rule thus:

```
alert tcp any any <> any !SHELLCODE_PORTS ( ... )
```

You could also do:

```
portvar SHELLCODE_PORTS [!21,!25,!80,!143,!587,!8889]
```

Which should be valid syntax.  Haven't tested, though.  YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, Im trying it as
portvar SHELLCODE_PORTS [!21,!25,!80,!143,!587,!8889]
but I still seem to get Executable code detected notifications...

Comment: I would do the original form of definding the ports non-negated to SHELLCODE_PORTS, then negate the variable.  It reads easier.

Comment: what about the rule updates from surely these will be affected by this change?

Comment: I don't believe they change variables very often.  You can always peruse by hand the config file they pass down.  Oinkmaster can also help to manage little changes like that, too.  For your specific variable, I believe Snort upstream has always defined $SHELLCODE_PORTS as !80, so I don't see that changing very often.

Answer (score 0):

You want !$SHELLCODE_PORTS

You are missing the dollar sign.